# Assembler Caesar cipher probably error with compare

Tags: assembly, syntax, x86, compare, encryption

I have a problem with my code about the Caesar cipher. I am not going to change my comments to English, but they aren't much anyway. The program is made out of two programs. One was coding the Caesar cipher, and the second one was decoding the Caesar cipher. I made it so when I press 0, it should run coding part, and when I press 1 it should run decoding part.

The coding program should work like this `"0" -> "abc" -> "A" -> "bcd"`, and decoding make "zab" instead.

Awfully, it makes both coding or decoding whenever I press 0 or 1. So for example, if there is:

```
cmp $'0' , %bl
je LOOP1

cmp $'1' , %bl
je LOOP2
```

the program will run after 0, and after 1 coding. If I change it like it looks on full code, it will run decoding even if I press 0 (the same as 1). So probably there is an error with compare..

Full code:

```
SYSCALL = 0X80
STDIN = 0
STDOUT = 1
SYSREAD = 3
SYSWRITE = 4
SYSEXIT = 1
EXIT_SUCCESS = 0

.data
msg_hello: .ascii "0-kodowanie 1-dekodowanie"
msg_hello_len = . - msg_hello

WYBOR_MAXLEN = 1
WYBOR: .space WYBOR_MAXLEN
WYBOR_LEN: .long 0

TEXT_MAXLEN = 64
TEXT: .space TEXT_MAXLEN
TEXT_LEN: .long 0

KEY_MAXLEN = 2
KEY: .space KEY_MAXLEN
KEY_LEN: .byte

.text
.global _start

_start:
#wczytanie powitania
mov $SYSWRITE, %eax
mov $STDOUT, %ebx
mov $msg_hello, %ecx
mov $msg_hello_len, %edx
int $SYSCALL

# wczytanie 01
mov $TEXT_MAXLEN, %edx
mov $TEXT, %ecx
mov $STDIN, %ebx
mov $SYSREAD, %eax
int $SYSCALL

mov %ebx, WYBOR_LEN # wybor

# wczytanie tekstu
mov $TEXT_MAXLEN, %edx
mov $TEXT, %ecx
mov $STDIN, %ebx
mov $SYSREAD, %eax
int $SYSCALL

mov %eax, TEXT_LEN # rzeczywista dlugosc wczytanego tekstu

#wczytywanie klucza
mov $KEY_MAXLEN, %edx
mov $KEY, %ecx
mov $STDIN, %ebx
mov $SYSREAD, %eax
int $SYSCALL

mov %eax, KEY_LEN # dlugosc klucza

xor %edx, %edx
movb KEY, %dl
sub $'A', %edx
add $1, %edx

mov $WYBOR_LEN, %ebx

cmp $'0' , %bl
je LOOP1

#cmp $'1' , %bl
jne LOOP2

#szyfr cezara
#klucz w edx

LOOP1:

mov $0, %ecx # licznik petli
sub $1, TEXT_LEN

ENCRYPTION_LOOP:
mov TEXT(, %ecx, 1), %eax #przesuwamy aktualny znak do rejestru al
cmp $'A', %al
jb DONT_ENCRYPT_CHAR
cmp $'z', %al
ja DONT_ENCRYPT_CHAR
cmp $'Z', %al
jna ENCRYPT_CHAR
cmp $'a', %al
jb DONT_ENCRYPT_CHAR

ENCRYPT_CHAR:
add %edx, %eax
cmp $'z', %al
jae CORRECT_CHAR_CODE
cmp $'a', %al
jae CHAR_CODE_OK
cmp $'Z', %al

ja CORRECT_CHAR_CODE
jmp CHAR_CODE_OK
CORRECT_CHAR_CODE:
sub $26, %al
CHAR_CODE_OK:
movb %al, TEXT(, %ecx, 1)
DONT_ENCRYPT_CHAR:
add $1, %ecx # inkrementacja licznika petli
cmp %ecx, TEXT_LEN
jne ENCRYPTION_LOOP

add $1, TEXT_LEN

jmp WYSWIETL

LOOP2:

mov $0, %ecx # licznik petli
sub $1, TEXT_LEN

DECRYPTION_LOOP:
mov TEXT(, %ecx, 1), %eax #przesuwamy aktualny znak do rejestru al
cmp $'A', %al
jb DONT_DECRYPT_CHAR
cmp $'z', %al
ja DONT_DECRYPT_CHAR
cmp $'Z', %al
jna DECRYPT_CHAR
cmp $'a', %al
jb DONT_DECRYPT_CHAR

DECRYPT_CHAR:
sub %edx, %eax
cmp $'A', %al
jb CORRECT_CHAR_CODE2
cmp $'Z', %al
jbe CHAR_CODE_OK2
cmp $'a', %al
jb CORRECT_CHAR_CODE2
jmp CHAR_CODE_OK2

ja CORRECT_CHAR_CODE2
jmp CHAR_CODE_OK2

CORRECT_CHAR_CODE2:
add $26, %al

CHAR_CODE_OK2:
movb %al, TEXT(, %ecx, 1)

DONT_DECRYPT_CHAR:
add $1, %ecx # inkrementacja licznika petli
cmp %ecx, TEXT_LEN
jne DECRYPTION_LOOP

add $1, TEXT_LEN

jmp WYSWIETL

WYSWIETL:
#wyswietlanie tekstu
mov TEXT_LEN, %edx
mov $TEXT, %ecx
mov $STDOUT, %ebx
mov $SYSWRITE, %eax
int $SYSCALL

EXIT:
# zakonczenie programu
mov $EXIT_SUCCESS, %ebx
mov $SYSEXIT, %eax
int $SYSCALL
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some bugs here:

```
#wczytywanie klucza
mov $KEY_MAXLEN, %edx
mov $KEY, %ecx
mov $STDIN, %ebx
mov $SYSREAD, %eax
int $SYSCALL

mov %eax, KEY_LEN # dlugosc klucza

xor %edx, %edx
movb KEY, %dl 
sub $'A', %edx
add $1, %edx

mov $WYBOR_LEN, %ebx ; ebx = number of characters

cmp $'0' , %bl ; bl = and(0xff, number of characters)
je LOOP1

cmp $'1' , %bl ; bl = and(0xff, number of characters)
# jne LOOP2    ; this should be je LOOP2, not jne LOOP2

#szyfr cezara
#klucz w edx

LOOP1:
```

You don't compare the key, but `$WYBOR_LEN`, because of this:

```
mov $WYBOR_LEN, %ebx
```

Then even if by chance `bl` wouldn't be `'0'` (`0x30`) or `'1'` (`0x31`), you don't have any error-handling, so the code continues anyway to `LOOP1`.

To fix the bugs you could do something like this:

```
xor %edx, %edx
movb KEY, %dl
sub $'A', %edx
add $1, %edx

movb KEY, %bl   ; store the value from KEY to bl before comparison.

cmp $'0' , %bl
je LOOP1

cmp $'1' , %bl
je LOOP2

; print here some message to inform user that the input is invalid.

jmp _start

#szyfr cezara
#klucz w edx

LOOP1:
```